# WPF Binding to three level ObservableCollection<T> property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, observablecollection

I have 3 level subclasses with `ObservableCollection<T>` properties of each other. In `MainViewModel` I created `ObservableCollection<Group>` property which elements of `Group` class will be in first level in `TreeView`. In every `Group` class I created child `ObservableCollection<Parameter>` property. And in the end in `Parameter` class I created `ObservableCollection<ParameterValue>` for store values. Note: every class based on `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Let's to go the code.

`Models.cs`:

```
//BaseModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged
public class ParameterValue: BaseModel
{
    private DateTime dateTimeValue;
    public DateTime DateTimeValue
    {
        get { return dateTimeValue; }
        set
        {
            dateTimeValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DateTimeValue");
        }
    }

    private double value;
    public double Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
}

//BaseModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged
public class Parameter: BaseModel
{
    public Parameter()
    {
        values = new ObservableCollection<ParameterValue>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ParameterValue> values;
    public ObservableCollection<ParameterValue> Values
    {
        get { return values; }
        set
        {
            values = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Values");
        }
    }

    private int parameterId;
    public int ParameterId
    {
        get { return parameterId; }
        set
        {
            parameterId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ParameterId");
        }
    }

    private string parameterName;
    public string ParameterName
    {
        get { return parameterName; }
        set
        {
            parameterName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ParameterName");
        }
    }
}

//BaseModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged
public class Group: BaseModel
{
    public Group()
    {
        parameters = new ObservableCollection<Parameter>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Parameter> parameters;
    public ObservableCollection<Parameter> Parameters
    {
        get { return parameters; }
        set
        {
            parameters = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Parameters");
        }
    }

    private int groupId;
    public int GroupId
    {
        get { return groupId; }
        set
        {
            groupId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    private string groupName;
    public string GroupName
    {
        get { return groupName; }
        set
        {
            groupName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("GroupName");
        }
    }
}

//Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged
public class BaseModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

`ViewModels.cs`:

```
//BaseModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged
public class MainViewModel: BaseModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>();

        //fill sample data instead of recieving from DB
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            Group group = new Group { GroupId = i, GroupName = "Group " + i.ToString()};
            groups.Add(group);
            for (int j = 1; j < 11; j++)
            {
                Parameter param = new Parameter { ParameterId = j, ParameterName = "Parameter "+j.ToString()};
                for (int k = 1; k < 51; k++)
                {
                    ParameterValue val = new ParameterValue { DateTimeValue = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(i*j-k), Value = (1000-k*5)/((i+j)+1)};
                    param.Values.Add(val);
                }
                group.Parameters.Add(param);
            }
        }

        int l = 0;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Group> groups;
    public ObservableCollection<Group> Groups
    {
        get { return groups; }
        set
        {
            groups = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Groups");
        }
    }
}
```

And MainWindow.xaml in View role:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TreeView x:Name="trv" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" />
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ParameterName}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
    <ListView Grid.Column="1" Background="Bisque" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Groups.Parameters}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Date Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateTimeValue}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

In `MainViewModel` I simplify data receiving from DB replacing by nested for loops with test data.

1. I try to make showing selected in `TreeView` `Parameter` data in `ListView`   in MVVM way.
2. In `DataGroup` necessary to create `SelectedItem` property of `Parameter` class for more accurate data recieving from DB? Of course in MVVM way.

Comment: What's the issue you're facing? Are you not getting any data displayed?

Comment: @dhilmathy Yes, I'm not see any data because something in Binding wrong.

Comment: Binding seems fine for me, how are you setting your `DataContext`? Are you able to see something in your `ListView`?

Comment: @dhilmathy In MainWindow constructor I set DataContext = new MainViewModel(); Nothing show in ListView...

Comment: What if you start with a simple listbox to bind to?

Comment: @J.vanLangen I try later with listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ListView ItemSource you have to bind to the Values like so...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TreeView x:Name="trv" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" />
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ParameterName}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
    <ListView Grid.Column="1" 
              Background="Bisque" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Values, ElementName=trv}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Date Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateTimeValue}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Observer how I binded to the SelectedItem of your TreeView. That selected item is expected to be the parameter which has property Values.

If you select Group than nothing will be displayed since Group does not have Values collection. Only Parameter has that.

Comment: Wow, so simple solution! And little question: When I select Group elements in TreeView I get "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Values' property not found on 'object' ''DataGroup'". Is there any trick to clear this?